# Adding a component to a dynamically rendered window list in React.JS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, components, state

Currently running into an issue trying to render a component as a part of a list window in react.js. The way my code stands now, I have hard coded a `items` list which is filled with a song name just for the sake of testing. I have a Row Component, which is simply a row in my window list. I build a row component by going through the `items` list and then add that row to the window.

As it currently stands the `items` list must be hard coded for it to work however I am trying to allow a user to fill out an input box, which then builds a row component, and then adds the row component to the window list. Here is what my code currently looks like:

```
import React from 'react'
import { FixedSizeList } from 'react-window';
import RowComponent from './RowComponent';
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';

const items = [
    "National Anthem"
];

const Row = ({ index, style }) => (
    <RowComponent artistName={items[index]} num={index} style={style} />
);

function SongList() {

//Update List
const [list, setList] = React.useState(items);
const [name, setName] = React.useState('');

//Track input fields state
function handleChange(event){
    setName(event.target.value);
}

//Add items
function handleAdd(){
    const newList = list.concat({name, id: uuidv4()});
    setList(newList);
    setName('');
}

//console.log({list});
return (
<div>
    <FixedSizeList
    height={600}
    width={450}
    itemSize={75}
    itemCount={list.length}
    className="list-container"
>
    {Row}
</FixedSizeList>
<div className='adder'>
    <input type="text" value={name} onChange={handleChange} /> 
</div>
<div class="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto">
    <button class="btn btn-primary m-3" type="button" onClick={handleAdd}>Add Song</button>
</div>
</div>

);
}

export default SongList;
```

I am trying to use states to do this. Using the input box and the button towards the bottom I call the `handleChange` and `handleAdd` functions which recognize something is being added.

The issue lies in my `handleAdd` function where I can only seem to add the name of the song typed in but not make a new row component from that name which I am attempting to do.

I tried the following line in the `handleAdd` function: `const newList = list.concat({    <RowComponent artistName={name} num={uuid4} style={(empty for now)} /> , id: uuidv4()});` but no luck.

I'm struggling to build a new row component and add it so that the window recognizes that it was added. Any suggestions?

Comment: Where are you applying the `list` state?

Comment: @Aleksandar, I thought I was applying it in `handleAdd` where I am setting a new list with a new name added to the list, however instead of a new name being added I wanted to add an entire row component.

Answer (score 0):

Your logic makes sense, you're just missing the actual map from your items array to rows. Currently you're only rendering:

```
{Row}
```

Instead, you should use map whenever you want to render a collection of items:

```
{ items.map( (item, index) => <Row artistName={item} ...> ) }
```

And while you're at it, you can edit your items state by just doing:

```
...
let newItem = {whatever here};
setList(list => [...list, newItem])
...
```

This should get you there I believe.

Comment: Thanks for the response! I'm trying to replace `{Row}` with `    { items.map( (item, index) => <RowComponent artistName={item} num={index} style={style}/> ) }
` but now the error that `style` is not defined. I ran into this issue earlier and couldn't figure out how to pass `style`.

Comment: Maybe you've figured it out, but yes you have to pass style, but that's just something your Row component requests, which I don't know what it is used for in this case.